# Firebase + React Native - Grab each Document ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been stuck on this for ages trying to figure out how I can console log each Firebase Cloudstore document ID separately when I press onto each rendered FlatList item.

I can grab a certain key / id by using `onPress={() =>{console.log(this.state.posts[0].key)}}` etc. But I dont know how to grab each one separately. In essence I only want the document ID of the touchableOpacity I have pressed. Not just [0]

Screenshots are below of App layout so you can get an understanding and also code example

**PostsLayout.js**

```
export default class PostsLayout extends React.Component {

  render() { 
    const {summary, stringTime, user} = this.props;

    return (         

        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.container}
          onPress={this.props.onPress} 
        >
            <PostsUser user={user}/>
            <PostsSummary summary={summary}/>
            <PostsDate time={stringTime}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

**FlatListLayout.js**

```
    export default class FlatListLayout extends React.Component { 

    render() { 
        return ( 
                <ScrollView >
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.props.data}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <PostsLayout {...item} onPress={this.props.onPress}/>}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

**ScreenLayout.js**

```
export default class ScreenLayout extends React.Component { 

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    db = firebase.firestore()
    path = this.db.collection('usersData').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("posts")


    onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
        const posts = [];    
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
                const {summary, time, stringTime, user, userId} = doc.data();

                posts.push({
                    key: doc.id, doc, summary,
                    time, stringTime, user, userId
                });
            });

            this.setState({
                posts
            });

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
        this.setState({currentUser})

        this.unsubscribe = this.path.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate) 
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe(); 
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
        <FlatListLayout
            data={this.state.posts}
            onPress={() => {console.log(this.state.posts[0].key)}}
        />
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Here is an example of my app screen. Each grey box is a touchableOpacity and when I click it onto it I want to console log the firebase cloudstore document ID]

Thank you for reading this and please help :)

Comment: I guess I have a solution for your issue, tell me this first, `PostsFunction` did you mean `FlatListLayout`?
If not where is `PostsFunction`?

Comment: Ah yea sorry that was a mistake - I’ll edit now. If you have solution that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the easiest fix would be send a function argument from the original press event in the child level.
For example,  PostsLayout has the main onPress, so on this call just send back any data you need, each component will have specific data related to the component. As each react child is unique.
PostsLayout.js

```
export default class PostsLayout extends React.Component {

  handleOnPress = () => {
   const { onPress, index } = this.props;
   if( typeof onPress === 'function') {
     onPress(this.props, index); // here pass anything you want in the parent level, like even userm stringtime etc
   }
  }

  render() { 
    const {summary, stringTime, user} = this.props;

    return (         

        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.container}
          onPress={this.handleOnPress} 
        >
            <PostsUser user={user}/>
            <PostsSummary summary={summary}/>
            <PostsDate time={stringTime}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

FlatListLayout.js

```
    export default class FlatListLayout extends React.Component { 

    render() { 
        return ( 
                <ScrollView >
                    <FlatList 
                        data={this.props.data}
                        renderItem={({item, index }) => <PostsLayout {...item} index={index} onPress={this.props.onPress}/>}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

ScreenLayout.js

```
export default class ScreenLayout extends React.Component { 

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    db = firebase.firestore()
    path = this.db.collection('usersData').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("posts")


    onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
        const posts = [];    
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
                const {summary, time, stringTime, user, userId} = doc.data();

                posts.push({
                    key: doc.id, doc, summary,
                    time, stringTime, user, userId
                });
            });

            this.setState({
                posts
            });

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {currentUser} = firebase.auth();
        this.setState({currentUser})

        this.unsubscribe = this.path.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate) 
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unsubscribe(); 
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
        <FlatListLayout
            data={this.state.posts}
            onPress={(data, index) => {console.log(data); console.log(this.state.posts[index].key)}}
        />
        )
    }
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Updated the answer with key as well. :)

Comment: Brilliant thank you - I won’t be able to test it until tomorrow but if it works I’ll select as correct answer :)

Comment: Brilliant answer Kundu! It helped me a lot, a easy way to return a array of objects with key included as result.