# Update a single document base on id in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update a single document in firestore base on its id?

I want to update a single "announcement" based on its id but I don't have any clue on how I can achieve that.

I'm thinking if I can pass the id of the document to editFunction and from there update the document base on the passed id.

Below is my code that retrieves the data:

```
retrieveAnnouncement = () => {
    const announcements = [];
    const id = []
    /* retrieve announcements */
    firebase.firestore().collection('announcement').get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          announcements.push(doc.data());
//here is the unique id that I will use later on to update a single document
          console.log(doc.id)
        });
        this.setState({ content: announcements, docID: id });
        console.log(announcements)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
editSingleAnnouncement = () => {
//get the unique id of an announcement and update it.
}
```

and here, it renders the data coming from firestore:

```
_renderAnnouncement = ({ item }) => 
//display the content of announcement
  <Card>
    <Text h3>{item.TITLE}</Text>
    <Text h5>{item.CONTENT}</Text>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Edit" containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 80}} />
      <Button title="Delete" buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 80}} />
    </View>
  </Card>
```

and renders

```
render () {
  return (
    <View>
    <ScrollView>
      <FlatList data={this.state.content} renderItem={this._renderAnnouncement} keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
    </ScrollView> 
    </View>
  )}
```

here's the image of my app

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3l2l.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3l2l.png)

Comment: You'll indeed need the ID of each document in the `_renderAnnouncement` function. If that ID is not part of your item, you can pass it into the function explicitly. See this question/answer for an example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842905/firebase-react-native-grab-each-document-id

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) is clear on how to update a document when you know its ID:

```js
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
return washingtonRef.update({
    capital: true
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
});
```

You will need to build a DocumentReference to the document to update, including the name of the collection and document ID, then call `update()` on it.

In your case, to build a reference to a document in announcements:

```
const id = "..."
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('announcement').doc(id)
```

You will have to provide that ID.